# iOS Vuforia error after entering from background

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, augmented-reality, vuforia

I use Vuforia SDK, version 6.2.9 in my iOS App.
All work's fine, but there is an error when the app enter from background.

The viewcontroller running VUFORIA is listening for **UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification** and **UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification** notifications. 
In the case of UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification pause AR, in the case of UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification resume AR.

```
// we use the iOS notification to pause/resume the AR when the application goes (or come back from) background

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(pauseAR)
 name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
 object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(resumeAR)
 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
 object:nil];
```

These are the methods

```
- (void) pauseAR {
   NSError * error = nil;
   if (![vapp pauseAR:&error]) {
      NSLog(@"Error pausing AR:%@", [error description]);
   }
}

- (void) resumeAR {

    NSError * error = nil;
    if(! [vapp resumeAR:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error resuming AR:%@", [error description]);
    }

    // on resume, we reset the flash
    Vuforia::CameraDevice::getInstance().setFlashTorchMode(false);

    [self handleRotation:self.interfaceOrientation];
}
```

When I return to the scan mode, after the app has entered from background, the camera is frozen, with error 
**Could not find a UIView with CAEAGLLayer or CAMetalLayer layer class that responds to selector renderFrameVuforia**

```
2017-07-17 11:13:01.187406+0200 App[8689:2961061] frame: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
2017-07-17 11:13:01.243707+0200 App[8689:2961061] DEBUG/AR(8689) Could not find a UIView with CAEAGLLayer or CAMetalLayer layer class that responds to selector renderFrameVuforia
2017-07-17 11:13:01.253958+0200 App[8689:2961061] Vuforia Library version 6.2.9
2017-07-17 11:13:01.731099+0200 App[8689:2961061] AR View: Rotating to Portrait
2017-07-17 11:13:01.731406+0200 App[8689:2961061] frame: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
2017-07-17 11:13:01.731562+0200 App[8689:2961061] VideoBackgroundConfig: size: 750,1334
2017-07-17 11:13:01.731589+0200 App[8689:2961061] VideoMode:w=1280 h=720
2017-07-17 11:13:01.731611+0200 App[8689:2961061] width=750.000 height=1334.000
2017-07-17 11:13:01.731638+0200 App[8689:2961061] ViewPort: X,Y: 0,0 Size X,Y:750,1334
2017-07-17 11:13:02.598959+0200 App[8689:2962160] INFO/AR(8689) 2017-07-18 11:13:02: Completed CloudReco transaction with ID '6f5c61ecc07741a7b652242abf909479'
2017-07-17 11:13:02.843834+0200 App[8689:2961061] frame: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
2017-07-17 11:13:02.844215+0200 App[8689:2961061] frame: {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
2017-07-17 11:13:02.860971+0200 App[8689:2961061] DEBUG/AR(8689) UIView has CAEAGLLayer layer class
2017-07-17 11:13:02.861114+0200 App[8689:2961061] DEBUG/AR(8689) UIView does not respond to selector renderFrameVuforia
2017-07-17 11:13:02.861191+0200 App[8689:2961061] DEBUG/AR(8689) UIView has CAEAGLLayer layer class
2017-07-17 11:13:02.861222+0200 App[8689:2961061] DEBUG/AR(8689) UIView does not respond to selector renderFrameVuforia
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application -- try adding code inside this method

Comment: Do you mean the "pauseAR" method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which method you call `pauseAR()` ?

I faced the same issue when popped back to the ViewController(which own the EAGLView) the camera is frozen.

I call `pauseAR()` in `viewWillDisappear()` and `resumeAR()` in `viewWillAppear()`, as the issue came out the delegate method `renderFrameVuforia()` in EAGLView never get called, I think this is problem cause the issue:

> Could not find a UIView with CAEAGLLayer or CAMetalLayer layer class that responds to selector renderFrameVuforia

So I looked up the Vuforia Developer Library and found:

> The app's view hierarchy is set up completely before calling QCAR::onResume() (at which point QCAR attempts to locate the app's view conforming to UIGLViewProtocol).

I changed `resumeAR()` method called position to `viewDidAppear()`, everything work as usual. Hope this can help you.

Comment: You didn't specify the filename of `viewWillDisappear()` and  `viewWillAppear()` and its path